# Is file sharing to iOS no longer available on iTunes for Windows? How can I transfer files from Windows to an app on an iOS device

Tags: ios, itunes, ipad, windows, file-transfer

I have some files stored on a Windows system that I'd like to transfer to an app on my iPad. Apple still has  [a page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201301) about using iTunes to copy files to an app on an iOS device. However, this option seems to be gone, as described [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252656277).

Here is a screenshot of the current iTunes on Windows with an iOS device connected.

[image]

How can I transfer files from Windows to an app on an iOS device?

Comment: I hate to be "that guy" but I always prefer 3utools over iTunes on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Just after I asked this question, I noticed that if I click on the iPad icon to the top left of iTunes (right to the "Music" dropdown), I can go into a separate screen, where File Sharing becomes possible.

[image]